# Natbib style showing the citation term in the references list

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am writing a PhD thesis that requires me to use both `\citet` and `\citep` style citations (thus requiring natbib, as far as I am aware). I want `citep` references to read `[Mitchell 2013]`, `citet` references to read `Mitchell [2013]` and want the reference list at the end to include the `citep` form, for example:

```
[Mitchell 2013]: Henry Mitchell, 2013. The Biography.
```

I'm not too fussed about the exact reference list style, but so far have been able to find any that replicate the `citep` text at the start, other than those which are numeric reference styles. If I don't use natbib then there are many reference styles that include the `citep` at the start, for example `these.bst`, but then I lose `citet`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: How about defining `\citet` for yourself? I.e.  `\newcommand{\citet}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} [\citeyear{#1}]}`

Comment: @Emiel Thanks, can you post it as an actual answer, since I suspect it may be the right answer in this case and I may well want to accept it (I certainly want to up-vote it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using natbib with `plainnat.bst`, assuming you have set `\bibpunct();A{},` first, you can define:

```
\let\oldBibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\oldBibitem[#1]{#2}\StrBefore{#1}{(}\ (\StrBetween{#1}{(}{)}):}
```

You also need to `\usepackage{xspace}` at the top.

This makes the entries appear as:

```
Mitchell (2013): Henry Mitchell, 2013. The Biography.
```

The bracket characters and placement can be easily modified by editing the macro.

Answer (score 1):

As requested: if you need `\citet` you could always define it like this:

```
\newcommand{\citet}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} [\citeyear{#1}]}
```

Comment: It seems `citeauthor` is only available with natbib? Can I use natbib but avoid it producing the reference list? Can I use `citeauthor` without natbib?

Comment: Wait, can't you use natbib (providing all the commands you need), and then use `\bibliographystyle{these.bst}` to get the output you need? (in that case my answer is rubbish but you're saved)

Comment: When combining the two I get: `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.` even after deleting all temporary files. If I could combine the two, I would have what I want.